# TFS and Time management

Tags: tfs

Hello i would like to know if its possible to have watches to monitor which task programmer is working on.. like some time tracker like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rauscha.apps.timesheet but integrated with TFS web service and for desktop.. im just trying to use TFS only for project scrum support but i need to know how many hours programmers spended on which task.. i guess in reality PM dont fill it manually so how it works in real projects ? Thank you

Comment: Like, wristwatches? How would that work?

Comment: Hello like TFS Working On which i found right now but it works strange maybe i just cant work with that because i can monitor time spended on PBI but not on task ?!

Comment: it works now i had selected bad query it works now, thanks :-)

Comment: This app still assumes that one work item is being worked on at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in real projects developers are required to track their own time. In an ideal situation the elapsed time would be the completed time - the assign time. This doesn't work generally as developers generally work on more than one task at a time.

Comment: Hello thank you.. i just found "TFS Working On" app which is what i searched for but im surprised that there programmer can track his time only on PBI but not on PBI task ? and he can fill remaining time for PBI which is really strange.. im little confused :P